# In cases like the one mentioned, can good/nice be interchangeable

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

He can't have **good** things because, he doesn't look after them.

He can't have **nice** things because, he doesn't look after them.

In cases like this are nice and good interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AmE, **nice things** is a collocation that refers to items of higher quality which tend to cost more than things which are not very nice.

> She has a lot of really nice things in her house.

The phrase **good things** does not typically have that materialistic sense, but tends to be used of other kinds of benefits:

> Patience, kindness, an optimistic disposition—these are all good things.

Comment: I thought that was "good" the one having that materialistic sense instead of "nice", at least according to the Cambridge Dictionary. I'm wrong and I should remove my answer, am I? [No irony]

Comment: @Rubio Ric: The dictionary is giving you the meaning of the word **good** in general contexts:  "It's a good car".  That is, the car functions well, is reliable, whatever.   But the meaning of a word in a collocation can trump the general meaning. Hence, **nice things** = things that are well made, high quality, stylish, often expensive, not "friendly, behaving pleasantly". **good things**  is not necessarily materialistic and very often it is not, referring to things that have spiritual or emotional or cultural value rather than materialistic, mercantile or functional value.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to say that "nice" means "things [I/he/she/we] _like_" (which contains higher quality items, but not exclusively)

Comment: "Things we like" is rather too broad, IMO, for this collocation.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence it would be "nice things", because 'things' here refers to material belongings and the sentence/expression is about their appearance, and not their function. So, for objects you would say "wow that's a nice mug/wallet/purse/etc" and not "wow that's a good mug/wallet/purse/etc", unless maybe you were talking about the function of the object specifically ("this is a really good purse because I can fit all my stuff in it").

Also, "He/she/we can't have nice things" is a common expression, especially on social media these days.

Finally, there's no comma after "because". So the sentence should be

> He can't have nice things because he doesn't look after them.